# Data signal leads clock signal?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, signal-processing, digital-communications, signal-integrity

I’m reverse engineering some sort of proprietary serial protocol that has a clock and data line. I’m pretty sure I figured out the 6 byte message format to get the data I’m looking for. Using a scope it shows some of the data bits lead the clock and are read as zeros instead of ones. The protocol only makes sense if these bits are read as ones. So my guess is that these signals are getting delayed or chopped off somehow when I read the data line. This happens about 1-2 bits per 48 bits.

Here is an example of a bit that leads the clock pulse in error.

[image]

Now here is what a bit that reads as a one as expected looks like. It seems that a regular data pulse is wider and falls slower than the errored one above.

[image]

It’s difficult to say 100pct but it seems like it’s happening on random bits. Perhaps it’s not an error and this serial protocol does something with the data line when the clock goes low? I’m not an expert in serial protocols but not sure I’ve seen any that work that way.

Is this a data transmission line issue, something I’m doing wrong on the receiving side of the circuit, or is this as expected and it’s part of the protocol and I need to figure that out?

Comment: "The protocol only makes sense if these bits are read as ones" - do you have a specific reason to suspect that? (i.e. do you know what values are supposed to be in the data stream)

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed different. However, it is unknown why some bits drop early as if they were driven low or stay high and droop off slowly as if they were turned high-impedance and stray capacitances get discharged with weak pull-down.

But if you try to receive all bits in a way that is compatible will make it work.

If you just check has there been a rising edge on data line before rising edge on clock line, it is a one bit. If there has not been a rising edge on data line, it is a zero bit when clock rises.

Comment: Hmm...so design/program around the issue? I am using an interrupt triggered on the clock risking edge. How would I know what the data line was before? Maybe an interrupt on the data line that simply flips a flag that the clock interrupt can read?

Comment: @DaveInPA Yes if possible. The data interrupt sets a flag. The clock interrupt reads the flag and clears it.